# dividing items into bins and retrieving the counts in each bin

Tags: r, bins

I have a vector of continuous observations like so:

```
x = c(0,0.001,0.03,0.8,0.005,0.6,0.12,0.3,0.75,0.9,0.043,0.81,0.5,0.21,0.27,0.17,1,0.9)
```

I divide it to twenty bins like so:

```
cut(x, breaks=seq(0,1,by=0.05),include.lowest = TRUE)
```

How do I retrieve the number of elements that "fell" in each bin?
For example, how can I tell there are 5 items in the bin [0,0.05]?

Many thanks!!

Comment: Try `table(cut(x, breaks=seq(0,1,by=0.05),include.lowest = TRUE))`

Comment: Thanks but how do I get a vector with these counts? Sorry for the idiotic question... new to R...

Comment: It *does* give a vector with those counts. It is a named vector. `res <- table(cut(x, breaks=seq(0,1,by=0.05),include.lowest = TRUE)); attr(res,"names") <- NULL`.

Comment: `dimnames(res) <- NULL`

Comment: @rawr thanks, that was what I meant. I was wondering why `names(res)<-NULL` wasn't working

Comment: This worked for me: unname(res)     Thanks everybody!!

Comment: @SimonO'Hanlon you should probably cut and paste this as an answer so it can be accepted

Comment: @rrs I think it a duplicate and should be closed, but I can't be bothered to search for the dupe. Feel free to post it yourself if you want.